# Cookie gets set, but I can't see where

Tags: cookies, firebug

I am working on a site (that I can't give you access to), and have problems with understanding the way the cookie a set.

Here is the process:

1. Clear cookies and cache in FF
2. Log in, by submitting POST form

Here is the first request-response from FF Developer Tools' "Net" panel.

[image]

As expected, the browser does not send a cookie for this request, but surprisingly the server does not request a cookie to be set with a "Cookie-Set" header. And even more surprisingly, the very next request *does* send a cookie along.

Here is the subsequent request-response:

[image]

Where and when was this cookie set? Have I completely misunderstood how cookies are set?

Answer (score 0):

As you have attached a screen shot ,there is a tab is displaying in header named as "Cookies".

In this panel you can see the cookie and its value.

[image]

Comment: I know about the cookie tab, and it does tell me the cookie value. But that is not the issue here. I want to understand *when* and *where* it is set. The keyword is *understanding*. I need to understand this in order to do some screen scraping.

Answer (score 0):

It is set in JavaScript. I did not even consider this an option, but apparently that is possible.